# Pass arguments to custom component

Tags: nativescript

I created component and it will be nice to use it ;) but I don't know how 
to pass arguments;

Use:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
      xmlns:masterMenu="includes/customComponents/masterMenu">
    <masterMenu:masterMenu selected="1"/>
</Page>
```

How can I catch `selected` in component? Currently I have only *masterMenu.xml* and *masterManu.css* files.

---

**[ EDIT ]**

Let say I have component named `question` (pseudo code):

*xml*

> < StackLayout loaded="loaded">
>
> ```
> < Label text="Question: loremipsum" />
> < Label text="Answer 1" id="answer1" />
> < Label text="Answer 2" id="answer2"/>
> < Label text="Answer 3" id="answer3"/>
> ```
>
> < /StackLayout>

*js*

> exports.loaded = function(args) {
>
> ```
> var answerNo = args.answerNo,
>     page = args.object;
>
> page.getElementById(page, "answer"+answerNo).addClass('correct')
> ```
>
> }

*used* :

> < Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
>         xmlns:question="includes/customComponents/question">
>
> < question:question answerNo="2" />
>
> < question:question answerNo="1" />
>      < question:question answerNo="3" />
>
> < /Page>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript you would access it like this:

```
var menu = page.getViewById("idOfMenuComponent");
menu.selected;
```

That is assuming it's available to be accessed. That would all depend on how you have this component created. If it's not available you need to add the property to your component. Have a look at the `<Button>` module to see how this can be done.

Comment: This solution will work if I have one type of component on page but what if I had more than one?

Comment: It depends on how you have the component constructed, you could assign different ids, but again it all depends on how you build this component. Don't know much from the current context.

Comment: look at edit section, I know this code not work but I want something like this